# Beginner: about chaining

Tags: javascript

If I write:

```
var headerDiv = document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Chapter 1'));
```

What does the variable headerDiv point to, the div or the text node?

Comment: Is this a trick question? Answer: Neither. The value of the variable will be `undefined` because you get a type error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'createTextNode' of undefined`.

Comment: What if you check before you ask? SO isn't an online JS evaluator

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if you intended to chain a `.appendChild()` with the text node as an arg? Or maybe `document` was meant to be `.ownerDocument`?

Comment: yes, i meant to chain appendChild

Comment: Please update your question to show what you meant. And the answer is that the text node will be returned from `.appendChild()` (if that's what you're going to pass to it), and so that's what will be assigned to the variable.

Comment: ...of course you could find this out for yourself by logging the value to the console, or by reading documentation..

Comment: `console.log(headerDiv.nodeName); // #text` You could chain `.parentNode` on to the end if you wanted to assign the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the example is poorly chosen, so I will try to give an answer based on a different example. Imagine you have this code:

```
var foo = func1();
var bar = foo.func2();
var baz = bar.func3();
```

Here we store the result of each function call in a variable. This is useful if you want to reuse the result of a computation in multiple places.

But if you need the result only once, you can substitute the variable name with the expression that computed the value:

```
var bar = (func1()).func2(); // bar -> func1()
var baz = bar.func3();
```

Of course we can do this again for `bar`:

```
var baz = ((func1()).funct2()).func3();
```

This creates the same result as the code at the beginning. Only instead of saving the result of the intermediate steps, you use them immediately. The parenthesis wrapping the subexpressions are not necessary here, so the whole expression can be simplified to:

```
var baz = func1().funct2().func3();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't chain functions like that. `document.createElement('div')` will return the div element it creates. And `document.createTextNode('Chapter 1')` will return the text node it creates. When you write it like that the div will try to call on a function called document, which doesn't exist. Instead write:

```
var headerDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    textNode = document.createTextNode('Chapter 1');
```